# How to get parent's parent's parent's id in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent-node

I have a problem. I need to know how to get grandparent's ID in AngularJS.
I need "{{parent}}" to become "grand-parent". 
(it should be `<div id="me-and-my-grand-parent">`)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    var pid = document.getElementsByClassName("i-am-a-child");

    var pid = this.parentNode.id;

if (this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.id)
var pid=this.parentNode.id;

$scope.parent = var pid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="grand-parent{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div id="me-and-my-{{parent}}" class="i-am-a-child">
            </div>          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

My actual code

```
<li ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-class="{active: project.childToggle, '': !project.childToggle,hasChild: project.children.length > 0 }" ng-dblclick="childToggleCt(project)" id="project-{{$index}}">
  <div class="project-overview">
    <header class="clearfix flip-area">
      <span ng-if="!project.inCart" class="status dropdown-button warning pull-left" id="id-{{ParentIdShow}}" data-intro="Status bar" data-position="right">Pending</span>
```

And for now JS was like tis :

`$scope.ParentIdShow = function(obj)
            {
                alert(obj.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id);
            }`

Comment: Why do you need this id? that's a very weird requirement in an angular app.

Comment: That parent Id could have {{$index}} because it is ng-repeat div, and I need that div inside have unique id: parent is `id{{$index}}` so it is for example "id1", and child will be than "child-id1" - unique!

Comment: Your controller should be DOM-agnostic. Don't manipulate it, don't access, don't make assumptions about it. Manipulate only the scope. What you are trying to do goes against Angular's model/paradigm. To learn more, [read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: So... Why not use `<div id="me-and-my-id{{$index}}" class="i-am-a-child">` instead?

Comment: @AntonTemchenko your code sample does not have _ngRepeater_. Please post your actually code

Comment: @KevinB, it's not working like this, cause it's child element... i tried...

Comment: Post your actual code then, because it should work.

Comment: @Grundy

I pasted my actual code up here

Comment: @KevinB I ve putted my code

Comment: with your div samples it seems to work: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjc58bwm/), also you use function `ParentIdShow` wrong

Comment: This feels to me like an example of the XY Problem, and definitely not "Thinking in AngularJS".

Comment: @Claies  I agree. Just trying. Just studying. And need help. I didn't invent any other idea to make the div to have unique id inside other divs inside ng-repeater

Comment: @AntonTemchenko so why you think that you need id?

Comment: @AntonTemchenko are you try sample from this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjc58bwm/1/)? Are you try get something like this?

Comment: @Grundy Wow. no I wroted by myself the sample... ofcourse with google, but didnt see this sample. it can be the answer. I should check it

Comment: are you trying to set the Id for the elements so that some other library can find your elements? I really know the more I read this that it's an XY problem.  You have some sort of unknown *problem*, but instead of asking how to solve that problem, you came up with a *solution* that doesn't work, and frankly isn't making sense.  You really could help us help you by asking how to solve your *problem*...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: :-D ofcourse you can't see this fiddle because i create it 30 min ago

Comment: Anyway as say @Claies you have an `XY problem` so possibly if you explain your main problem, for example _why you need this id?_ we can help you more consistent

Comment: @Grundy I think my code can be not working because I have `<li ng-repeat>` in one file and all inside <li> is generating from another file... (

Comment: @AntonTemchenko so you need [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your current code because otherwise we can only guess what you really need and what you really try solve

Answer (score 0):

The answer to these types of "parent of my parent of my parent of my..." is to use the `controller as` syntax. Read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController). In short, it lets you do stuff like

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1 as first">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2 as second">
    ...
        <div ng-controller="ctrlN as Nth">
          <div ng-repeat="i in arr">
              {{first.property}}
              {{second.otherProperty}}
              {{Nth.nProperty}}
```

Note how you dont need any `parent` calls.

Comment: how it helps with `ngRepeat`?

Comment: @Grundy It works the same inside an `ng-repeat` (I presume thats what you're talking about). Ill update my example to make it clearer

Comment: in OP not used controllers, all inside `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Grundy What are you talking about? he creates a controller in his JS and he has `ng-controller=...` in his HTMl

Comment: i mean, he set id,depends on index, for element with ng-repeat attribute, and try use it id inside. it not use property from controller